# STL set with custom comparator allows duplicate elements

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

The following code is a simplified example that produces the problem.

A number of strings (char*) are inserted into a set, many of which are non-unique. Duplicate strings should be detected and a pointer to the original inserted should be returned; however, sometimes this doesn't happen and an already inserted string is inserted again as if it were not already present.

The resulting set should consist of: "aa", "bb", "cc".
The output shows the set ends up with: "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb".
Changing which string is first inserted seems to change which duplicate is 'allowed.'

The digit prefix on the strings are not used, but were added to ensure each string has a unique pointer; the problem does still exist without them.

Using the default comparator and non-prefixed strings does work as expected, but this only compares pointers; prefixing the strings results in unique pointers and all strings are inserted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::set;
using std::pair;

typedef set<const char*>::const_iterator set_iter;

struct cmp_op {
    int operator() (const char* x,const char* y) const {
        int r = strcmp(x,y);
        //cout << "cmp: " << x << ((r)?((r>0)?" > ":" < "):" == ") << y << endl;
        return r;
    }
};

int main() {
    //first char ignored, just ensures unique pointers
    const char* a[] = {"1bb","2aa","3aa","4bb","5cc","6aa","7bb","8cc","9bb"};
    const size_t n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);

    //using custom (strcmp) comparator
    set<const char*,cmp_op> s;

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        cout << "insert(" << (void*)(a[i]+1) << "=" << (a[i]+1) << ")" << endl;
        pair<set_iter,bool> r = s.insert(a[i]+1);
        if (r.second) cout << "OK";
        else {cout << "dup => " << (void*)(*r.first) << "=" << (*r.first);}
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    cout << n << " strings, " << s.size() << " unique:" << endl;
    set_iter it=s.begin();
    cout << (void*)(*it) << "=" << *it;
    while (++it!=s.end())
        cout << ", " << (void*)(*it) << "=" << *it;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.8.1 on windows; testing with Ubuntu produces the same result.

Answer (score 8):

Your comparison function does not implement a *strict weak ordering*, because it returns `true` whenever the LHS is not equal to the RHS. You need to change the logic to return true when one is "less than" the other. This is one example, which seems like a natural choice:

```
return r < 0;
```

Note that to make the intent clear, it would be better to return a `bool`:

```
bool operator() (const char* x, const char* y) const 
{
  return strcmp(x, y) < 0;
}
```

Comment: So the comparator is only a less_than, not a full compare? OK, now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @user3790259 It has to implement a strict weak ordering, so any sane "less than" or "greater than" will do. The choice is arbitrary if you don't care about the particular order of the elements in the set.

Comment: Think of it as `bool operator()` not `int operator()`